# Desenvolver layout com 3 colunas

Tags: html, css

Suponhamos que tenho um *layout* contendo 3 `divs` lado a lado.

A primeira dessas `divs` possui um tamanho fixo de `100px`, a terceira `div` não pode possuir tamanho fixo pois ela dependerá do texto inserido nela, contudo, ela não poderá quebrar o texto.

Já a segunda `div`, vai ter que se adaptar ao tamanho das outras `divs`. Dessa forma, ela será a única que poderá quebrar o texto. Como posso alcançar isso?

A imagem abaixo descreve melhor aquilo que pretendo fazer:

[image: Exemplo das 3 divs]

Comment: ja tento usa boostrap ? eu usaria uma table pra fazer essa linha ou um ajax que calcule o tamanho da terceira div e setasse o valor da segunda. mas com uma table seria bem mais simples

Comment: c vc quiser posso postar uma resposta utilizando table

Comment: Vou pesquisar a respeito... ATT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja se assim resolve seu problema

**css**

```
td span{
  font-size:30px;
  background:blue;
  width:auto;
  min-width:1px;
  text-align:right;
  float:right;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
td p{
  background:yellow;
  float:left;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   <table width="100%">
      <tr>
         <td width="100"><img src="imgaqui.jpg"></td>
         <td><p>SEU TXT AKI FORMATADO yg uyg yug uyg ykjg jg fyjkf ygf htj fhg fhg fgh f yjhf </p></td>
         <td width="1%" style="white-space:nowrap;text-align:right"><span>R$ 3,50</span></td>        
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td width="100"><img src="imgaqui.jpg"></td>
         <td><p>SEU TXT AKI FORMATADO</p></td>
         <td width="1%" style="white-space:nowrap;text-align:right"><span>R$ 153,50</span></td>       
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

segue o fiddle dele funcionando
https://jsfiddle.net/3mLffz19/

Comment: Eu havia feito com .resize() jquery, mas a sua solução é melhor. Gostaria de saber se há algum problema com a semântica em usar table na criação de um layout do tipo?

Comment: cara no meu ver não ha problemas pois ate o boostrap usa table para vários fins. vou dar uma pesquisada para ver se ha outra forma mais eficiente de fazer